# Можно ли запустить socket сервер на хостинге вместе с сайтом?

Tags: php, сокет, хостинг, websocket

Раньше с сокетами не работал. На хостинге запущен сайт, работает на instant cms. Мне надо там же запустить сокет-сервер. Я могу на том же сервере что и сайт запустить сокет?

Пробовал создавать по екшену инициализацию сервера (по примеру [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/198954/)).

Но на js не работает:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/socket:8081');
```

сервер недоступен:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/socket:8081' failed: Error during >WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Что делаю не так? может порт блокируется? надо настраивать хостинг для работы webSocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере использования websocket обращение идет к порту 8081. Соответственно на данном порту должно находиться какое-то приложение, которое будет отвечать на этот запрос.

Если вы делали по статье, то у вас должен быть запущен "демон", который будет слушать этот порт. Т.е. это не обычный скрипт, а по сути приложение, аналогичное веб-серверу.

Если же говорить о хостинге - тут многое зависит от того где вы будете размещать ваш сайт. Если это обычный шаред хостинг - то вряд ли получится. Но надо уточнять у поддержки хостинга. Если речь идет о VPS - то тут все в ваших руках.

И да - используемый порт (в вашем случае 8081) надо открыть на firewall для входящих соединений.

Comment: Судя по той статье, на примере которой топикастер пытается разобраться с websocket, то сервер у него должен быть. А вот подключается он вообще на localhost, а не на VPS или виртуальный хостинг.

Comment: Если вы делали по статье, то у вас должен быть запущен "демон"
Он запущен:

$server = IoServer::factory(
       new WsServer(
           new SocketRun()
       )
       , 8081
   );

   $server->run();
но почему-то не работает

Comment: @DavidGoloviy это PHP код. Т.е. у вас запущен файл с этим скриптом? И он висит в списке рабочих процессов?

Comment: я не могу посмотреть, т.к. сайт работает на чужом хостинге. но как я сейчас понял нет. Как добавить его в исполнение? получается он всегда должен быть запущен?

Comment: @DavidGoloviy да всегда. Как посмотреть и запустить- это к тем чей хостинг.